# Can't play .wav file with audioplayer xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, audio, xamarin.forms

I'm using [audio recorder plugin package](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder) to record and play audio in `Xamarin.Forms` Android application.
here is my code in mypage.cs:

```
private static readonly AudioRecorderService recorder = new AudioRecorderService
    {
        StopRecordingOnSilence = false,
        StopRecordingAfterTimeout = false,
        FilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.projectname/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".wav"
    };
    public RecordPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await recorder.StartRecording();
    }


    private async void Button_Clicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await recorder.StopRecording();
    }
    private void Button_Clicked3(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
        audioPlayer.Play(recorder.GetAudioFilePath());
    }
```

there is no issue with recording audio. the audio will record, save and play in system music players.
but when I want to play it with `AudioPlayer` class, it doesn't play anything. also there are no exception throws. I tried to play some audios with the .mp3 extension and it's working for them. also, it's working for .wav files which they're converted from .mp3 to .wav.
it has a problem just with the audios recorded by `AudioRecorderService`

please someone help me!

thank you

-- notice the anroid device I'm testing on it is `xiaomi poco x3 NFC, Android v-11`

edit :

`Xiaomi` was the reason of this problem. it's working with other devices.

Comment: I think your chances are better if you ask that question in the GitHub repo. It comes with an example project for recording and playback. Have you tried that? If it's not working I'd create an issue there.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride thank you very much. I saw many and many sample projects with this package. all of them use exact same code and it's working for them. but for me, it doesn't.