# Can't read output of AudioRecorder Xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, audio, xamarin.forms, wav

I'm using [Audio Recorder](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder) to record audio in Xamarin Forms.

but as I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70652655/cant-play-wav-file-with-audioplayer-xamarin-forms) I had a problem with playing the output of Audio Recorder with my Xiaomi Device.
and when I installed it on a Samsung Device and it works on it.
but when I tried to read and edit it with [NWaves](https://github.com/ar1st0crat/NWaves). I got this error :

```
System.IO.EndOfStreamException
Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
```

How I can make this output readable for Xiaomi devices and also NWaves?

Comment: you've already asked this question

Comment: @Jason there are not the same. this question is not talking about the device problems. this case shows the problem is with its bytes length or something else.

Comment: OK, but this question really lacks any useful detail.  There is no code, just an error message, so it will likely be closed anyway.

Comment: @Jason maybe, but what  I can do when my question has not got any answer with 32 views?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers